# Cannot launch Internet Explorer with WebDriverJs in Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I followed the directions at this link: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs and was able to get Chrome running.  I tried changing this line:

`var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
   withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).
   build();`

to:

`var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
   withCapabilities({'browserName':'internet explorer'}).
   build();`

I started my node with:

`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.42.1.jar -ro
le node  -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -Dwebddriver.ie.driver=IEDrive
rServer -browser browserName="internet explorer"`

and it continues to open in Chrome.  I'm using IE11 and I know there are some issues with IE11 but I followed the work around with the zone settings and registry key.  I cannot seem to even get the browser to launch.

Other info:
Using Windows 8.1 browser IE11

Answer (score 0):

You need to make 2 updates

1 - Update your capabilities

```
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.ie()).build();
```

2 - Update your ie.driver location in your node. At least, I see you missed ".exe" in the end of your driver configuration

Here's mine:

```
start java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -nodeConfig node.json -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="../res/chromedriver.exe" -Dwebdriver.ie.driver="../res/Iedriver.exe" -Dphantomjs.binary.path="../res/phantomjs.exe"
```

Good luck

Comment: when trying the first update it caused an error 'Object has no method internetExplorer'

Comment: please try again with var driver = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.ie()).build();

Comment: Something similar to results I've had in the past has no occurred.  Which is that it seems like it's doing something, but the browser never opens and i get lots of CSS warnings.  Here is a copy of the log: [link](https://gist.github.com/neptunian/e85943f8171c0f0d59c0)

Comment: By reading your log, the IE session is created, however there are some error in *your script* -> it could not be run

Please post your script in your question. Hope I could figure out what's wrong there :)

Answer (score 0):

As of Selenium version v.2.45.0, it now has native support for IE (which mean we dont need to install Selenium stand alone server. All you need to do is install the newest version of Selenium and turn on Internet Explorer protective mode for all zone.

Link to Selenium change log: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/CHANGES.md